# Error installing TensorFlow GPU on Ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I've spent my day trying to install TF GPU, without luck.

I've installed CUDA Toolkit 9.0 and tried CuDNN v7.0.3 (for CUDA 8 and 9) and also the v6.0.

After trying to execute my demo program, the terminal throws this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twicetwo.py", line 5, in <module>
import tensorflow
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/home/gemboly/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

I've updated the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable and also the `PATH`.

I'm using Anaconda, created a source with Python 3.6, since `python --version` threw this version.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: It's complaining that your cuda libraries were not found on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Can you double check by doing `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, cd to those directories (copy/paste, to ensure you don't have a typo in the path), and verify that you see libcublas.so.8.0 in one of those directories? Also make sure to log out of your shell and back in (or source .bashrc) to make sure all your paths are set after installation.

Comment: I have a GPU machine @ home, and I format it regularly.
If you ask me, to save yourself all the configuration, learn to use docker, and use it jointly with nvidia-docker to save yourself all of the trouble of configuring it by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to run it. If you are here because you are stuck like me do the following:

- use CUDA 8.0 (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)
  *for me only the runfile install worked!*
- I have Python 3.6 installed, but when creating your environment you should use python="3.5" instead